# Pause the background thread execution by using NSTimer not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to pause the thread operation by user's action which is running in the background. I used `NSTimer` to pause the thread, but when I am pressing the pause button all my program(screen) freeze, I am not able to press any button.

```
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
                                                  target:self 
                                                selector:@selector(calculationOfPIValue) 
                                                userInfo:nil 
                                                 repeats:YES];
```

Comment: What does your **calculationOfPIValue** actually do?  Does it calculate PI to the 10th digit only? Or does it calculate it to 1000th digits?

Comment: its calculating 100 digit

Comment: When **NSTimer** fires and call your method, it doesn't executes on the background thread.  If you want it to run on background thread, you will need to see @Vive answer below as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly what do you want to do.

You have a background thread (running it via `NSThread`? `NSOperation`? `GCD`?).

So, to run your PI calculation in the background and enable to cancel it you may use `NSOperation`.

So you create a new class called `MyPiCalculationOperation` and type:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface MyPiCalculationOperation: NSOperation
@end

@implementation MyPiCalculationOperation
- (void)main {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // paste your calculate PI algorithm, I put here any loop as an example
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            // in your loop check isCancelled flag
            if (self.isCancelled) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Please read http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/ for more reference.

In your controller you should start the operation somewhere. Below is just an example, as I don't know when do you want to start it:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSOperationQueue *queue;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    MyPiCalculationOperation *operation = [[MyPiCalculationOperation alloc] init];
    [self.queue addOperation:operation]; // this will auto-start when you add operation to the queue
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressedDown:(id)sender { // your button press handler
    [self.queue cancelAllOperations]; // to cancel
    // or use setSuspended to "pause" the operations
}
```

Comment: suspended also do the same think like cancel.

Comment: I am able to stop the thread by user's action. The problem is in Pausing the thread by user's action(button) and releasing it from the stopped point. Can you give me an idea how to do it.

Comment: "The problem is in Pausing the thread by user's action(button) " can you describe what do you mean? Because for me it means that on buttonPressed action you want to pause the thread? How do you do your thread?

Comment: yes. i want to pause the thread by buttonPressed and when user press the button again it should run  from the point where user stopped, not from the beginning.